# Ubuntu 18.04, dropbox icon gone after screen lock

Tags: ubuntu, icons, dropbox

Under Ubuntu 18.04, the Dropbox icon appears normally. However, if I lock the screen and unlock it, the icon is gone. The process is running in the background, but there's no icon. How to keep the icon?

Comment: Alt + F2 , type r then Enter is only fix  ; see :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113665/missing-app-indicator-icons-in-ubuntu-18-04